# Flutter: showMenu does not scroll to initialValue

Tags: flutter

I use the built-in `showMenu`. I can position it where I want. The issue is that if the menu list is very long and therefore has a scroll (I use this to select a group in a chat app) the menu does not scroll to the `initialValue`.

The `initialValue` is highlighted though.

The documentation itself says:

If `initialValue` is specified then the first item with a matching value will be highlighted and the value of `position` gives the rectangle whose vertical center will be aligned with the vertical center of the highlighted item (**when possible**).

Any suggestions or a 'better' package to use instead of `showMenu`?

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I used the scrollable_positioned_list package. See [https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list][1] 


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list

Comment: I also used the `scrollable_positioned_list` package and it worked well.